# HTTP header request in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, helmet.js

The idea of this app is that whenever any URL has been called, it's supposed to give HTTP response. And I am trying to send data to HTTP header but I have no idea how to populate the content and can't find anywhere the solution as well.

Here is my code

```
const express = require('express');

let helmet = require('helmet')


const app = express();

app.use(helmet());

app.use((req, response, next) => {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

const link = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
const data = [{ 'text' : 'Meeting Created',
                'attachment' : 
                    {'title':'Board Created', 
                        'text' : 'Visit this URL and share with your participants so that 
                            they can join.',
                        'title_link': link
                    }
                }];


const responseBody = {data};

response.end(JSON.stringify(responseBody))


 });

 const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

 app.listen(port , () => {
   console.log('Port is listening');
 })
```

After run the app .. i am getting following result in the header

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 08:17:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

But i want additional data in the HTTP header directives. just like below

Desired Output :

```
{
   "statusCode": 200,
   "content": "{\"text\":\"Meeting Created\",\"attachments\":[{\"title\":\"Join 
    Meeting\",\"text\":\"Visit this URL and share with your meeting participants so that 
    they can join: https://mnow.io/800244\",\"title_link\":\"https://mnow.io/800244\"}]}",
   "headers": {
    "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains",
    "x-download-options": "noopen",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "216",
    "etag": "W/\"d8-KMGsyQ3ByyfI5IsF7yiwJ86lLWw\"",
    "date": "Tue, 28 Apr 2020 08:11:19 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "data": {
  "text": "Meeting Created",
  "attachments": [
  {
    "title": "Join Meeting",
    "text": "Visit this URL and share with your meeting participants so that they can join: 
     http://localhost:4000/",
    "title_link": "http://localhost:4000/"
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: Your http response does not go in the headers.  It goes in the body of the response.  And, that's exactly where `response.end(JSON.stringify(responseBody))` puts it.

Comment: what if i want it in the headers ? can i do that ?

Comment: Headers are not for content like that.  That's just a misuse of http.  Headers are meant for single line `key: value` or sometimes `key: value1;value2;value3`.  You could probably find a way to encoded it and stuff it into a header, but just because it might be possible to do it, doesn't mean you should.  This data is the http response and it belongs in the body of the http response, not in a header.

Comment: can you help me .. how can i encode it in the headers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using response.writeHead(). I got desired output.

```
const express = require('express');

    let helmet = require('helmet')


    const app = express();

    app.use(helmet());


    app.use((req, response, next) => {

        const link = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
        const data = [{ 'text' : 'Meeting Created',
                        'attachment' : 
                            {'title':'Board Created', 
                                'text' : 'Visit this URL and share with your participants so that they can join:'+ link,
                                'title_link': link
                            }
                        }];

        const responseBody = {data};


        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8','data' : JSON.stringify(data)}); // Added This line


        response.end(JSON.stringify(responseBody))


    });


    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    app.listen(port , () => {
        console.log('Port is listening');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use express's [response.set](https://expressjs.coLm/en/api.html#res.set) function to set the header before sending a response.

Also, if your response is a JSON, then you don't need to set status code or content type explicitly. A simple [res.send](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) the call will do. Express will take care of rest.

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet')
const app = express();

app.use(helmet());


app.use((req, response) => {

    const link = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    const data = [{
        'text': 'Meeting Created',
        'attachment':
        {
            'title': 'Board Created',
            'text': 'Visit this URL and share with your participants so that they can join:' + link,
            'title_link': link
        }
    }];

    // You don't need to set content type for JSON response. The headers for that are set automatically by express.
    response.send({ data });
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Port is listening');
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried to set the response but it throws an error 
**Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**
i've added
`const responseBody = {data};
    response.set(data);`

what am i missing here ?

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to set data in the header.